# vuetify v-slider: How do I change the color of the message prop?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify sliders and populating the message property. How do I change the color of the message?

```
<v-slider app class="mx-4 my-0"
  v-model="currentNumCycles"
  thumb-label="always"
  thumb-color="red"
  track-color="red"
  min="1"
  max="10"
  ticks="always"
  step="1"
  tick-size="2"`enter code here`
  background-color="white"
  messages="Number of Cycles"
/>
```

EDIT:
I have tried using the css class .v-messages__message in my , but it doesn't work.

```
.v-messages__message {
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik there no option to change it via properties, but you can easily change it via css.

```
.my-0 .v-messages__message {
  color: #3a2424
}
```

Comment: After adding !important to the css class statement it worked.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to pass HTML element to the messages prop.

```
<v-slider app class="mx-4 my-0"
  v-model="currentNumCycles"
  thumb-label="always"
  thumb-color="red"
  track-color="red"
  min="1"
  max="10"
  ticks="always"
  step="1"
  tick-size="2"
  background-color="white"
  messages="<div class='white--text'>Number of Cycles</div>"
/>
```